# Tag/Label an image in an image field with Taxonomy terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, files, media

Is it possible to tag images as you upload them on to a node in a multiple values image field?

```
Image a node with a set of 3 images:
image_1.jpg (tagged with: red)
image_2.jpg (tagged with: blue)
image_3.jpg (tagged with: red)

And another node with 2 images:  
image_A.jpg (tagged with: red)
image_B.jpg (tagged with: green)
```

What I'm aiming to do is to be able to pull all the images tagged with the tag "red" in a view.

```
RED IMAGES
image_1.jpg (tagged with: red)
image_3.jpg (tagged with: red)
image_A.jpg (tagged with: red)
```

Is there a module that performs this?
Images have to be uploaded into the image fields. They cant be uploaded as nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) for this.  This creates a collection of fields that you can add and do exactly what you are looking to do.